# Символ "+" заменяется на пробел при Post-запросе

Tags: c#, post

В переменной `token` содержится значение `abc+abc`. Снифаю трафик через `HttpAnalizer`. Когда я посылаю данные через браузер в логах у меня этот токен нормально отображается, с символом `+`. Однако когда я делаю запрос через c# код знак "+" заменяется на пустоту, т.е на пробел. Я думал сперва проблема в кодировке, но не то. В логах все равно вылазиит `abc abc`.

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://xxx.ru");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
request.Referer = "http://xxx.ru/";
 request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2";
postData = string.Format("javax.faces.ViewState={0}&",token);
data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
request.CookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
```

Comment: Для url нужно экранировать символы, т.е. вместо `abc+abc` в url будет: `abc%2Babc`

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode();

Answer (score 2):

Если вы указываете тип передаваемых данных как application/x-www-form-**urlencoded**, значит вы должны передавать их именно в таком формате. Сделать это можно с помощью метода [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) или, если используете .NET 4.0+, [WebUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var encodedData = WebUtility.UrlEncode(rawData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Прогоните данные через [`Uri.EscapeDataString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Uri.EscapeDataString("abc+acb") // abc%2Bacb
```

А лучше - отнаследуйтесь от `WebClient` для поддержки Cookies:

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private CookieContainer m_container = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = m_container;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

И используйте стандартный метод [`WebClient.UploadValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx) вместо ручной работы с `HttpWebRequest`.